# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Composer\Installers\Test\TestCase' not found in PhpStorm

Tags: php, debugging, drupal, phpunit, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm. In settings, I am using Composer autoloader. The path to script is `autoload.php`. Unfortunately I run the debugger with an error saying

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Composer\Installers\Test\TestCase' not found in

What do I do now? Am I suppose to get a debugger for PhpStorm now? Why do each error expands and expands like a riddle? Do I have to wait next time on dragon ball z?

[image: PHPUnit Library]

[image: Fatal Error displaying the test case not found]

Comment: Thing you should wait for `The wizard of oz`. How do you thing anyone can help here? Composer & PHPStrom[debugger] There can be everthing wrong from basic configuration to ..whatever

Comment: You may start with providing some relative screenshots. So far it looks like some misconfiguration from user end.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the idea with images. I can only add two, because I do not have a repuation of 10 and above. I dont mind switching to phpunit.phar but i get an error there as well. You think there is a school that can teach me this? Because I dont have enough material to be self taught PHP Storm. A book would help.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Hi thanks for the reply. What is the wizard of oz? Is that a upcoming patch, composer update, or a admin on here that specializes with PHPstorm? I researched phpstorm wizard of oz but couldnt find anything involving PHP Storm let alone composer. Thanks

Comment: It meant to be Composer's autoloader (right now you seem to point to some custom one) .. so the typical one would be `PROJECT_ROOT\vendor\autoload.php`. If you need to use your own autoloader -- consider including it via bootstrap file (PHPUnit provides such options).

Comment: In case of books/manuals/how-tos -- have a look at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials

Comment: Testing-related articles in particular: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Testing+PHP+Applications

Comment: I still receive the error when pointing towards the autoload.php within vendor. However, Thank you for the resources, I am going to use these! I am going to start again using the resources you provided me with. Thank you.

Comment: Try with brand new project and very simple test case first just to ensure that it all works. Once done -- try with your real project. If still nothing -- ensure that it works from command line/terminal using PHPUnit directly.

Comment: `The wizard of oz` is a movie like `dragon ball z` has a movie...,-) was just a ironic statement to your first question version. Hopefully the term `dragon ball z` is not used in the php world ,-)